# javascript newline replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I Have a regex to replace the `color` value from a given string it works well when there is no newline like the following...

```
 var BodyContent = "background-color:red;color:white";

  // NOTE : there is no new line constant  

 var dis = BodyContent.replace(/(^|;)color:\s*([^;]+)/, "$1color:" + 'green'); 

 //returns dis ="background-color:red;color:green"; //Works well
```

But not work when like this

```
BodyContent = "background-color:red; \n color:white;"; // Note the newline constant

var dis = BodyContent.replace(/(^|;)color:\s*([^;]+)/, "$1color:" + 'green');

//returns dis = "background-color:red;color:white"; there is no change.the color is still white
```

This is my regex to replace the color value  `/(^|;)color:\s*([^;]+)/` .

> Now how can i do with this new line also ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.  First, you need to set the multiline flag on your regexp if you want `^` to match after a newline in the middle of the search string.  Second, you put "`\n`" (with spaces) in your second `BodyContent`.  Your regexp doesn't handle the spaces after the newline.

Try this:

```
/((?:^|;)\s*)color:\s*([^;]+)/m
```

Answer (score 1):

### The solution

```
var dis = BodyContent.replace(/(^|[;\n\s]+)color:\s*([^;]+)/, "$1color:" + 'green');
```

### Explanations

Your regular expression `/(^|;)color:\s*([^;]+)/` matches the a color which is either the beginning of a string (^) or prefixes with an `;`. It fails in the following cases:

```
"background-color:red; \n color:white;";
```

The 'color' is prefixes by an whitespace(\s).  In some cases, it may also be prefixed by an newline(\n);

```
"background-color:red; \ncolor:white;";
```

So to match in these cases, you use the the regular expression `(^|[;\n\s]+)color:\s*([^;]+)`. It matches the 'color' string in four cases:

- In the beginning of a string: `"color:white;"`
- Prefixed by an `;`: `"background-color:red;color:white;"`
- prefixed by one or more new line: `"\ncolor:white;"`
- prefixed by one or more spaces: `"   color:white;"`

Comment: Fails if `color` is the first thing in the search string.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow for whitespace after the semicolon (or beginning of the string) but before "color". You should allow for whitespace before the colon, too:

```
/(^|;|\n|\s+)color\s*:\s*([^;]+)/
```

You may also want to allow for if the color property is the last thing before a closing curly-bracket }:

```
/(^|;|\n|\s+)color\s*:\s*([^;}]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dis = BodyContent.replace(/([\s;{]color:)\s*[^\s;}]+/, "$1green");
```

Unless you're processing the text one line at a time, there's no need to treat the linefeed specially.  It's just another whitespace character, and you need to match any of those; that's what `\s` is for.  There's no need to match the beginning of the string either, so you don't need the `^` anchor.

However, you should allow for the opening brace, in case "color:" is the first declaration in the rule.  For example:

```
H1{color:white;background-color:red;}
```

Additionally, given this valid rule:

```
H1{background-color:red;color:white }
```

...your regex would match `;color:white }` and replace it with `;color:green`, resulting in invalid CSS.  That's why I changed the second character class from `[^;]` to `[^\s;}]`.